# VS2010 C# cant see non overridden methods of controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am new to C# and wrote a simple winform with a list box with manually added items.  I want to add code to the `listbox` mouse double click method but I cannot locate it anywhere - not even sure it is called `mousedoubleclick`.  During edit if I double click on the list box it puts me into the `SelectedIndexChanged` method but all other default methods do not show in the drop down box on the top right.  So how do I get to other methods?  I manually coded it but it does not run at runtime.

In all other Visual Studio and VB all used/unused methods are visible for a control/object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `MouseDoubleClick` event for a `ListBox`.  `MouseDoubleClick` is an event on `Control`, so all controls must inherit that event.

You can either locate the list of all possible events in the designer to add an event handler:

[image]

or simply do so through code in the form's load event:

```
listbox1.MouseDoubleClick += MyDoubleClickEventHandler;
```

Visual studio can even auto-generate a method stub with the proper signature when you type that out.

Comment: +1 for showing an image of where to find the event using the designer and how to add the event through code using the form's load event.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the lightning bolt, that is what I was missing.  Working now.